# How to prevent NA of dates when using rbind?

Tags: r

I essentially have two df's that I'd like to bind w/o merging by column. I bind them so that the updated df can follow below the previous one. Everything works find except that the date formats are different, trying to adjust gives me NA values.

Not sure if there's another way to change formats. Any suggestions?

Reprex

```
# 1
rating <- 1:4
date <- c('2021-12-19', '2021-12-20', '2021-12-21', '2021-12-22')
name <- c('ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL')
title <- c('Manager', 'Accountant','QA','IT')
df1 <- data.frame(rating,date,name,title)
print(df1)

# 2
rating <- 1:4
date <- c('12/15/22', '12/16/22', '12/17/22', '12/18/22')
name <- c('MNO', 'PQR', 'STU', 'VWX')
title <- c('Cyber', 'Broker','D&T','IT')
df2 <- data.frame(rating,date,name,title)
print(df2)

df1$date <- as.Date(df1$date, format = "%d-%m-%y")
df2$date <- as.Date(df2$date, format = "%d-%m-%y")
both <- rbind(df1,df2)

print(both)
  rating date name      title
1      1 <NA>  ABC    Manager
2      2 <NA>  DEF Accountant
3      3 <NA>  GHI         QA
4      4 <NA>  JKL         IT
5      1 <NA>  MNO      Cyber
6      2 <NA>  PQR     Broker
7      3 <NA>  STU        D&T
8      4 <NA>  VWX         IT
>
```

Comment: `rbind` is not your issue - all the dates in `df1` and `df2` are `NA` *before* you bind them together. Your `as.Date` `format=` is not correct as you need to align the specified format to how the dates are actually stored as text originally.

Comment: Should have been: `df1$date <- as.Date(df1$date)` since the character version of those dates were in standard order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace your date format as follows:

```
df1$date <- as.Date(df1$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
df2$date <- as.Date(df2$date, format = "%m/%d/%y")
both <- rbind(df1,df2)
both
  rating       date name      title
1      1 2021-12-19  ABC    Manager
2      2 2021-12-20  DEF Accountant
3      3 2021-12-21  GHI         QA
4      4 2021-12-22  JKL         IT
5      1 2022-12-15  MNO      Cyber
6      2 2022-12-16  PQR     Broker
7      3 2022-12-17  STU        D&T
8      4 2022-12-18  VWX         IT
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked really well. @thelatemail, touched on it but could you explain what exactly the issue was? And say I wanted it to be mm/dd/yy would I just do the reverse?

Comment: @caveman You may benefit from reading [this explanation](https://www.statology.org/r-date-format/) of date formatting in R